# Conditionally add fields to JSON output

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have a couple types, `User` and `Post`. A `Post` is created by a `User`.

My database looks the same as my types, which are

```
data User = { userID :: Integer, name :: String }
data Post = { content :: String, authorID :: Integer } -- authorID is the userID
```

Assuming I have valid To/FromJSON instances based on those types, how would I go about conditionally including a value in the output of my JSON?

As an example, I may want to look at a users "profile", which would include all `Post`s made by the `User`. Other times, I may want to search through the various `User`s in the system, so there is no point in returning the `Post`s that they have made.

I have no problem retrieving the `Post`s for a given `User`, nor do I have an issue retrieving the `User` of a given `Post`. I just want to know the best way to conditionally add a key to my JSON.

Someone mentioned to me that I should essentially add a field to `User` for `posts :: Maybe [Post]` and add an `author :: Maybe User` to my `Post` type. While this would work for rather small types, I feel that it would make certain types with a lot of relations quite large and potentially hard to maintain.

I've also thought of using a `Map Text Data.Aeson.Value` to build / serialize my information, but you lose most (all?) type safety by doing something like that.

**EDIT**

Based on the data types above, I have defined the following ToJSON instances.

```
instance ToJSON User where
  toJSON (User i n) = object [ "id" .= i, "name" .= n ]

instance ToJSON Post where
  toJSON (Post c a) = object [ "content" .= c, "author_id" .= a ]
```

This would give me "simple" json output, something like `User`:

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "User Name"
}
```

`Post`:

```
{
  "content": "This is the content of my post",
  "author_id": 4
}
```

These can be useful, especially when searching for items. This allows to only show a limited amount of information.

I could do something along the lines of

```
instance ToJSON User where
  toJSON (User i n) = object [ "id" .= i, "name" .= n, "posts" .= posts i ]
```

Which would give me the Users information, as well as all posts associated with that user, assuming a valid definition of `posts`.
This would give me JSON similar to

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "User Name",
  "posts": [
    {
      "content": "This is some content",
      "author_id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I do not understand how I would be able to dynamically set which fields I would like to send down to the client. Is it possible to define multiple instances of ToJSON and choose which instance I would like to use for a given request? Or should I just do what was suggested before and include a `posts` field in my `User` type that can hold a `Maybe [Post]`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question yet. What makes it hard to conditionally include a value? Can you give a short-ish example where your JSON includes "too much" and ideally also why you think it's hard to include less?

Comment: @DanielWagner I made an edit, I hope it clears things up a little.

Comment: Can't you just... sidestep the typeclass? I mean, you can write as many functions as you want of type `Foo -> Value`, they don't *have* to be named `toJSON`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a general answer to whether you should use dynamic JSON or stick to fixed `ToJSON` instances, but you can easily mix the two and add extra fields to JSON values that are generated from your instances.

From what you've written I guess you know Aeson represents an object as a `Map Text Value`? For arrays it uses `Vector Value`.

So you can call `toJSON` on your `User` and on the list of `Posts` and just insert the post array as an additional entry in the map if you want it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as M

data User = User { userID :: Integer, name :: String }

data Post = Post { content :: String, authorID :: Integer }

instance ToJSON User where
    toJSON (User i n) = object [ "id" .= i, "name" .= n ]

instance ToJSON Post where
    toJSON (Post c a) = object [ "content" .= c, "author_id" .= a ]

babs = User { userID = 5, name = "babs" }

posts = [ Post { content = "blah", authorID = 5 } ]

userWithPosts = Object (M.insert "posts" v o)
  where
    Object o = toJSON babs
    v        = toJSON posts

main = B.putStrLn (encode userWithPosts)
```

The `encode` call gives you the combined JSON:

```
*Main B> main
{"name":"babs","id":5,"posts":[{"author_id":5,"content":"blah"}]}
```